# Remove Windows 10 and keep Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: windows

Windows 10 has video problems and I need to remove and use Ubuntu 20.04.01 solely. I'm an old Geek that has limited computer skills. Need a kind, skilled person to help me.
Thanks, John

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps you have to follow:

1. Boot with Windows and backup data.
2. Then restart the machine and boot into Ubuntu.
3. Opens Disks or GParted.
4. Delete the Windows partition.
5. Expand the Ubuntu partition into the free space you got by deleting the Windows partition.
6. Apply changes.
7. Run `sudo update-grub` to remove the Windows entry from the dual boot menu.
8. And restart

Comment: steps worked and windows uninstalled!!